# No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, sessionfactory, hibernate-entitymanager

Currently I'm facing an issue in Autowire configuration between controller and the service layer, however I receive a Dependency Injection issue.I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE application with JPA.I defined repository interfaces and implementations.

UserRepositoryInterface :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserRepositoryInterface extends JpaRepository<Account,Long> {
@Query("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.userName = :username")
Account findByLogin(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

UserSchoolRepositoryInterface :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserSchoolRepositoryInterface extends JpaRepository<UserSchool, Integer> {

@Query("select s.id " + "from Account u,School s,UserSchool us "
        + "where  u.id=?1 " + "and us.userId = u.id "
        + "and us.schoolId = s.id")
Integer findSchoolByUserId(Long id);
}
```

I was using Oauth2 for Authorization.

Main :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}
}
```

OAuth2AuthorizationConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${check-user-scopes}")
private Boolean checkUserScopes;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Bean
public OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory() {
    CustomOauth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new CustomOauth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    requestFactory.setCheckUserScopes(true);
    return requestFactory;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    converter.setKeyPair(new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "password".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("keystore"));
    return converter;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Bean
public TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter tokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, requestFactory());
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    if (checkUserScopes)
        endpoints.requestFactory(requestFactory());
}
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService :

```
@Service(value = "userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


@Autowired
private UserRepositoryInterface userRepositoryInterface;
@Autowired
private UserRoleRepositoryInterface userRoleRepositoryInterface;
@Autowired
private UserSchoolRepositoryInterface userSchoolRepositoryInterface;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String input) {
    Account user = userRepositoryInterface.findByLogin(input);

    if (null == user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "INVALID USER WITH LOGIN: " + input);
    } else {
        List<String> userRoles = userRoleRepositoryInterface.findRoleByUserId(user.getId());
        Integer userSchool = userSchoolRepositoryInterface.findSchoolByUserId(user.getId());
        return new CustomUserDetails(user, userRoles, userSchool);
    }
}
}
```

CustomOauth2RequestFactory :

```
public class CustomOauth2RequestFactory extends DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory {

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public CustomOauth2RequestFactory(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    super(clientDetailsService);
}


@Override
public TokenRequest createTokenRequest(Map<String, String> requestParameters,
        ClientDetails authenticatedClient) {
    if (requestParameters.get("grant_type").equals("refresh_token")) {
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = tokenStore.readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(
                tokenStore.readRefreshToken(requestParameters.get("refresh_token")));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), null,
                        userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName()).getAuthorities()));
    }
    return super.createTokenRequest(requestParameters, authenticatedClient);
}
}
```

Below are my rest controller class and services.

LoopController :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class LoopController {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
@Autowired
public LoopDao loopDao;
public static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Gson gson;
GsonBuilder builder;

@RequestMapping(value="/checkCategoryName",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String checkCategoryName(@RequestBody String categoryName){
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Account customUser = accountService.findByUsername(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
    School school = customUser.getUserSchool().getSchoolId();
    System.out.println("school : "+school.getName());
    String jsonAccts = null;
    long count = loopDao.checkCategoryName(categoryName,school.getId());
    System.out.println("count "+count);
    return (count == 0)? "no" : "yes";


}              
    }
```

LoopDao :

```
public interface LoopDao {

long checkCategoryName(String categoryName, int id);
}
```

LoopService :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LoopService implements LoopDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private org.hibernate.Session getCurrentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public long checkCategoryName(String categoryName, int id) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    try {
        long count = (long) session.createQuery("select count(name) from Category where name = :catName and schoolId = :schoolId")
                .setParameter("catName", categoryName).setParameter("schoolId", id).uniqueResult();
        return count;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public int createCategory(Category category) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Serializable genid = session.save(category);
        tx.commit();
        return Integer.parseInt(genid.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

build.gradle :

```
group 'com.lss.loopserver'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
baseName = 'LoopServer'
version =  '0.0.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
compile('javax.inject:javax.inject:1')
compile ('mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6')
compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1')
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RC2"
}
}

bootRun {
sourceResources sourceSets.main
}
```

application.yml :

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: clientapp
      clientSecret: 123456
      authorized-grant-types: authorization_code,refresh_token,password
      scope: openid
    resource.jwt:
      key-pair:
        alias: keystore
        store-password: password
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://192.168.1.2:8333/LoopServer/oauth/token
      prefer-token-info: true
server:
  port: 8333
  servlet:
    context-path: /LoopServer
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3306}/${db.name:loopschool}?useSSL=false
    username: ${db.uid:root}
    password: ${db.pwd:}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    tomcat:
      test-while-idle: true
      validation-query: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate:
      id:
        new_generator_mappings: true
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
      ddl-auto: validate
  application:
      name: LoopServer
  jmx:
      default-domain: LoopServer
  servlet:
      multipart:
        max-file-size: 30MB
        max-request-size: 100MB
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
check-user-scopes: true
debug: true
```

My application won't start with the message :

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:253) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.getUserConfigurationResults(NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.java:147) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.AbstractInjectionFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractInjectionFailureAnalyzer.java:41) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:36) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:114) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:107) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:848) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:832) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.lss.loopserver.Main.main(Main.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:440) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2019-05-07 16:11:16.364 ERROR 6700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loopController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loopDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loopService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loopService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem.
The problem comes after i migrated from spring boot 1.5 to spring boot 2.1.2
where most of the things in earlier versions has been deprecated including the way accessing sessionfactory.

Solution :
 Use below code

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

private org.hibernate.Session getCurrentSession(){

    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
}
```

Instead of

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private org.hibernate.Session getCurrentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

I got the solution from [this](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-5-example) link